# dataTable not loading php bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have an index.php page which has a button.On button click, I am getting a response which should be in a datatable model.

```html
<script src="../../js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/validate.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({});

  //button click for getting the response 
  $('.item').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: path, //loaddata.php
      data: {},
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        //  This div will have the example table contents which should be dataTable
        $('.response_div').html(data); 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I am getting the response without dataTable effects available.I have changed the order of jquery library, css files but no effect.

The libraries are loading.there is no error in console also.
Please help me
[image]

Comment: Put the `$('#example').DataTable()` call inside the AJAX callback, *after* you populate the table. Better still, use DataTables itself to make the AJAX calls for you. Then you can do server side filtering and paging which will have *much* better performance.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got it.Thanks. If you put it as an answer,i can accept it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have some issues with design. The pagination is not in the correct way. I think some styles are missing

Comment: You need to include datatables.css as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You mean I need to include the css file in the loaddata.php also. I have already loaded these files inside index page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry I got it..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Now the only issue I face is the pagination style missing.How can i get that.